# jpg addition to qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, qgis-2, jpg

I'm having lots of trouble with my jpg showing up on my qgis template. I have saved the image in the same folder as my .qgs file, so it should come with associated files. As you can see, the thumbnail is loaded, but only the portion of the thumbnail in the far upper left of the image is transferred to my canvas.

Georeferencing the image does not work either - the image loads in the georeferencer and I'm able to associate 4+ points to my coordinate system on the canvas, but when it converts it to my canvas, nothing shows up. I assume this is because the only part of the image that shows is the tiny portion in the upper left of the image.

This problem is driving me crazy!!! Please help???

[image]

Comment: It possibly is a georeferencing or coordinate system issue. Did you have a look at the image metadata? Did you perform the georeferencing yourself? Without more information it's not easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: I think it is a coordinate system issue, although I don't understand what has changed and why I can't import any jpg, even pre-georeferencing. An error comes up every time I add a raster "CRS was undefined: defaulting to CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. Can you point me in the direction to go reading for more help?

Comment: There are lots of resources online about coordinate systems. A quick [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002mq000000) goes here but you can be sure to find tonnes of material on the subject.